# New string list shuffles order of list elements on initialization in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, list

After running into some frustrations with my ASP.NET 5 API project I decided to rebuild it as an older WebApi 2 project.  I'm trying to generate a list of collections of 2 strings (originally a list of a 2 element string array, now a list of list of strings) from a LINQ query.

Here is the pseudocode that worked as I wanted it to in the ASP.NET 5 project:

```
var testList = db.MyTable.Where(x => [WHERE Clauses]).Select(x => new string[] { x.Number.Trim(), x.Name.Trim() }).ToList();
```

The new project choked on the query citing it didn't like using string arrays for whatever reason (I'm assuming difference in EF 6 vs 7?).  As a fix I instead had the query return a list of string lists but it mixes up the order of the "Number" and "Name" fields it returns, sometimes the Number is the first element and other times the Name is.  Here is some new query code attempts I tried that all ended up with the jumbled element order:

```
var testList = db.MyTable.Where(x => [WHERE Clauses]).Select(x => new List<string> { x.Number.Trim(), x.Name.Trim() }).ToList();
var testList = db.MyTable.Where(x => [WHERE Clauses]).Select(x => (new string[2] { x.Number.Trim(), x.Name.Trim() }).ToList()).ToList();
var testList = db.MyTable.Where(x => [WHERE Clauses]).Select(x => new List<string>(new string[] { x.Number.Trim(), x.Name.Trim() })).ToList();
```

I realize there are a ton of different ways to get the end result I'm looking for but I'm hoping someone can help me understand why these list elements would be placed in the list in differing orders (sometimes Name then Number other times Number then Name), even when I generate a list based on a newly created array which preserved the order perfectly previously.

Comment: That seems pretty unlikely. Are you *sure* your data is correct? Can you reproduce this? Are the same rows wrong every time? What happens if you stick a `.ToList().` before the `Select`?

Comment: As Blorgbeard said, it does seem more likely the data is incorrect. However, selecting an array or list, I would assume, is a pretty rare case for EF. Perhaps you did find an edge case. Try this: `var testList = db.MyTable.Where(x => [WHERE Clauses]).Select(x => new { Number = x.Number.Trim(), Name = x.Name.Trim() }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new List<string> { x.Number, x.Name }).ToList();`. Which will cause the list to be constructed *after* EF has done its work. If that still produces incorrect values, you can be almost sure it's because the data is bad.

Comment: The data is definitely correct, it is customer records from the master customer table of our Great Plains 2015 ERP software, bad data here would cause havoc on the whole company and I'd certainly hear about it, plus it worked flawlessly with the original string array code.  @Rob your suggestion fixed the issue, for whatever reason constructing the list after the LINQ query fixes it, post it as an answer and I'll accept it if you'd like.  Still wish I knew what was going on but I'll take working code as a win, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be curious to see what SQL is generated for those queries and whether or not it changes when your result changes. Selecting a List to me seems like a pretty rare situation, so it's possible you have run into an edge-case (or at least into undefined behavior territory).

Since you're still essentially just selecting two columns, we can worry about how the data is structured after Entity Framework has finished it's work

```
db.MyTable.Where(x => [WHERE Clauses])
    .Select(x => new { Number = x.Number.Trim(), Name = x.Name.Trim() })
    .AsEnumerable() //Force EF to materialize the result here
    .Select(x => new List<string> { x.Number, x.Name }) //Manipulate the result in memory
    .ToList();
```