# LINQ To Entities returns list data in the wrong order

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, deferred-execution

I have the following query, using the entity framework:

```
var results = (
from v in SomeTable
select new
{
    Something = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }
});
```

The resulting output is:

```
A,B,C
C,B,A
A,B,C
C,B,A
.
.
.
```

I can fix the problem by adding ToList() to SomeTable, like this:

```
var results = (
from v in SomeTable.ToList()
select new
{ 
    Something = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }
});
```

Why does this happen? What I can do about it?  I want to avoid the ToList() workaround since that forces the entire query to run on the client.

NOTE: My real query is more complex, I'm not really selecting just static data like that.  But this is my [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I found that the question is bit confusing , can you please elaborate `Something = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }` how it is actually , and what is the flaw in the data , means what you want vs what you got.

Comment: What about: `Something = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }.OrderBy(x => x)`

Comment: I've seen something similar a while ago (can't find the post). It appears the *order* of a `List<>` is not guaranteed to be preserved when you're selecting it. Assuming you have other columns in your select, I'd advise selecting out those columns, *then* running `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` to materialize the query, and then finally apply your in-memory select on all previous columns plus `Something`

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907460/new-string-list-shuffles-order-of-list-elements-on-initialization-in-linq/

Comment: @Rob Yes, that is exactly what I am doing.  My real query is Something = new List<string> { v.column1, v.column2, v.column3 }.  I will try AsEnumerable() instead of ToList() in case that helps.

Comment: @teovankot OrderBy(x => x) won't work with my real data isn't actually alphabetical.  My simplified example made it look that way, sorry.